# How do you support adding items to nested flowlayoutpanels?

Tags: c#, flowlayoutpanel

I have a flowlayoutpanel (flowParent) on a form that hosts a list of flowlayoutpanels (flowchild1, flowchild2, etc).

from the form level, how do i add an item to flowchild1. essentially, how do i reference the child flowlayoutpanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either retain the reference when you add that panel to the outer panel, or use Container.getComponent(int).